# UIImagePickerController added as subView and getting memory error

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

UIImagePickerController added on view as subView and open camera 2-3 time app get crash.
"Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates."
"Received memory warning"

```
UIImagePickerController * imagePickerController = [UIImagePickerController new];
            imagePickerController.view.tag=view.tag;
            imagePickerController.delegate = self;
            if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

                [imagePickerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, KCameraViewHeight)];

                [self.view addSubview:imagePickerController.view];"

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{

    [picker.view removeFromSuperview];
    [picker removeFromParentViewController];



}
```

Comment: Where have you written above initialization code? in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad?

Comment: Try if making `imagePickerController` a property fixes the issue.

Comment: I am facing this issue in old iPad. They 32-bit support with 512 MB ram.

Comment: Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <WFXFinalResult_ViewController: 0x15dc1e00>.
2017-01-25 18:49:21.296 WFX_QualityControl[9378:980108] Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.
2017-01-25 18:49:22.266 WFX_QualityControl[9378:980210] Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x34bab654> { count = 1, contents =
 "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x34bab854> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }